# Structuring downloaded JSON file in R

Tags: r, json, data-structures, finance

I have downloaded a historical time series of the Apple Income statement from this website:

https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/financials/income-statement/AAPL

Using this code:

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)
raw_data <- getURL("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/financials/income-statement/AAPL")

> *"<pre>{\n  \"AAPL\":{\n    \"Revenue\": {\n            
>       \"2013-09\": \"170910\",\
>       \"2014-09\": \"182795\",\n 
>       \"2015-09\": \"233715\",\n 
>       \"2016-09\": \"215639\",\n  
>       \"2017-09\": \"229234\",\n ........"*
```

How do I start to structure the data (ideally in a data frame)?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `jsonlite` to parse the data after you remove the **pre>** tags from the raw data (the interrupt the parsing process). Then you can convert the resulting *list* into a *data frame*  with `tibble` and then use `tidyr` to unnest everything.

```
raw_data %>% cat
clean_data <- stringr::str_replace_all(raw_data, '<pre>', '')
aapl_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(clean_data) %>%
  tibble::enframe() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(value = purrr::map(value, function(x){
    tibble::enframe(x)
  })) %>%
  tidyr::unnest() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(value = purrr::map(value, function(x){ tibble::enframe(x)})) %>%
  tidyr::unnest() %>%
  tidyr::unnest()
```

you should end up with something like this:

```
# A tibble: 102 x 4
   name  name1           name2   value 
   <chr> <chr>           <chr>   <chr> 
 1 AAPL  Revenue         2013-09 170910
 2 AAPL  Revenue         2014-09 182795
 3 AAPL  Revenue         2015-09 233715
 4 AAPL  Revenue         2016-09 215639
 5 AAPL  Revenue         2017-09 229234
 6 AAPL  Revenue         TTM     239176
 7 AAPL  Cost of revenue 2013-09 106606
 8 AAPL  Cost of revenue 2014-09 112258
 9 AAPL  Cost of revenue 2015-09 140089
10 AAPL  Cost of revenue 2016-09 131376
# ... with 92 more rows
```

Comment: I never thought I'd see something that mandated so many repeated `unnest`s, but this certainly did, nice job. Not *as* critical in answers as it is in questions, it's generally preferred to include actual text instead of images of text. A good list of reasons not to use images is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272), notable to me being: screen readers, search engines, and mobile device screens.

Comment: thank you for bringing this up. I just made the change. I'll try to be better about this in the future.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your answer. I don't seem to get the name of the measure when I run the code.  i get: "AAPL, 2013-09, 170910"

Comment: I've updated the code to  include the measure, ('revenue')

Comment: Another btw: you can replace `purrr::map(value, function(x){ tibble::enframe(x)})` with a slightly-more-readable `purrr::map(value, ~ tibble::enframe(.x))` or even `purrr::map(value, tibble::enframe)`. Part code-golf, part readability.

Comment: I knew about `purrr::map(value, tibble::enframe)`, but I'm not super comfortable with `~` notation. It's definitely something I need to get better about.

Answer (score 1):

Bringing string functions to HTML is like bringing a knife to a gunfight (i.e. generally not a good idea). Use some basic HTML transforms and then some targeted wrangling:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

pg <- read_html("https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/financials/income-statement/AAPL")

html_node(pg, "pre") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  jsonlite::fromJSON() -> xdat

map2_df(names(xdat[[1]]), xdat[[1]], ~{
  data_frame(
    measure = .x,
    period = names(.y),
    value = as.numeric(unlist(.y))
  )
}) %>% 
  mutate(company = names(xdat)) %>% 
  select(company, measure, period, value)
## # A tibble: 102 x 4
##    company measure         period    value
##    <chr>   <chr>           <chr>     <dbl>
##  1 AAPL    Revenue         2013-09 170910.
##  2 AAPL    Revenue         2014-09 182795.
##  3 AAPL    Revenue         2015-09 233715.
##  4 AAPL    Revenue         2016-09 215639.
##  5 AAPL    Revenue         2017-09 229234.
##  6 AAPL    Revenue         TTM     239176.
##  7 AAPL    Cost of revenue 2013-09 106606.
##  8 AAPL    Cost of revenue 2014-09 112258.
##  9 AAPL    Cost of revenue 2015-09 140089.
## 10 AAPL    Cost of revenue 2016-09 131376.
## # ... with 92 more rows
```

Comment: good point, I guess I was more focused on the `JSON` part than the extraction part.